# Specific Tags in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a following snippet from a CSS style sheet,

```
.header {min-height: 62px; background: #191919 url("images/header.png") bottom repeat-x;}

.header>div {width: 940px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto;}

.header p {margin: 0;}

.header p.title {float: left; max-width: 450px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 17px 10px 0; background: url("images/header-separator.png") right center no-repeat; color: #fff; font: normal 1.833em/42px MuseoSans,sans-serif;}

.header p.title a {color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

I know header is a class but I am not able to understand other tags in the code. Can someone explain me with a sample html?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble understanding, can you clarify?

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the web about css and selectors. For instance http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Comment: Also, something that someone might want to check out when IE matters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.header` = element/s `class` 'header'

`.header>div` = elements `div` children of `.header`

`.header p` = elements `p` childrens of˙`.header`

`.header p.title` = elements `p` with class 'title' - childrens of `.header`

`.header p.title a` = elements `a` clildrens of `p.title` children of `.header`

Answer (score 2):

```
.header > :tag:
```

means you are looking for an element `:tag:` who is directly descendent of element `.header`, so this will match:

```
<header class="header">
   <div>
   ...
   </div>
...
```

but this won't match

```
<header class="header">
   <section>
      <div>
      ...
      </div>
   ...
```

The other selectors are looking for generic nested elements of .header element:

- a paragraph inside .header
- a paragraph with class .title inside .header
- a link inside a paragraph with class .title inside .header

Answer (score 1):

heres a sample that uses all of that css. 
[live preview](http://onthemouse.com/files/sample.htm)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.header {min-height: 62px; background: #191919 url("images/header.png") bottom repeat-x;}

.header>div {width: 940px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto;}

.header p {margin: 0;}

.header p.title {float: left; max-width: 450px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 17px 10px 0; background: url("images/header-separator.png") right center no-repeat; color: #fff; font: normal 1.833em/42px MuseoSans,sans-serif;}

.header p.title a {color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase;}
</style>
</head>
<div class="header">
<div>
<img src="images/swag.jpg" width="100%" height="20px" />
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<p class="title">This is a Title <br /><a href="http://onthemouse.com">this is a link</a></p><br />
<p>this is a paragrapgh</p>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation of elements:
.header a**(link under header class)**  {min-height: 62px; background:**(color hex code)** #191919 **(url to bg picture>)**url("images/header.png") **(position, repeat horizontal)**bottom repeat-x;}

.header>div **(div inside header class)**{width: 940px;**(width any image or object inside this div set to 100% width will have this width)** overflow: hidden; **(no margin)**margin: 0 **(position auto, repeat auto)**auto;}

.header p*

(

tag under header class)

* {margin: 0;}

.header p.title 

(

tag with class title)

 {float: left;**(alignment:left)** max-width: 450px;**(maximum width)** margin: 0; **(sapce on sides)**padding: 10px 17px 10px 0; background: url("images/header-separator.png") **(position centered right, no repeat)**right center no-repeat; **(color white)**color: #fff; **(font size, and family)**font: normal 1.833em/42px MuseoSans,sans-serif;}

.header p.title a 

(link in

tag with title class)

{**(color white)**color: #fff; **(capital letters)**text-transform: uppercase;}

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of available tutorial in the web on CSS selectors.

I would recommend [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/index.htm). For detailed explanation of your selections see the [class selectors](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm) chapter and the chapter on [child selectors](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_child.htm).

See also [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/), this article provides a great overview.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .header p.title a {color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

would translate to

```
  <div class="header">
          <p class="title">
                   <a href="some link">All of this text would be WHITE and UPPERCASE</a>
          </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header>div means child div of .header class

.header p means assign this css to each and every p tag inside .header class

.header p.title means .title class of p of .header class

.header p.title a means a tags in .title class inside p tag of .header class
```

Comment: I am trying to use the ".header p.title {float: left; max-width: 450px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 17px 10px 0; background: url("images/header-separator.png") right center no-repeat; color: #fff; font: normal 1.833em/42px MuseoSans,sans-serif;}
" but its not showing desired results.

Comment: what you dont get.. all css or only background